# Reading a file and uppercasing non-ascii characters before saving the content to other file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file `in_file.ini` that contains the following strings:

```
67000 0 0 "La máquina debe de estar sin pieza"
67002 0 0 "Los Autocalibrados no están retrocedidos"
```

I want to take the content between the `" "` and save it in uppercase in a certain way on an output file `out_file.ini`:

```
alm_siem_alarm0=LA MÁQUINA DEBE DE ESTAR SIN PIEZA
alm_siem_alarm1=LOS AUTOCALIBRADOS NO ESTÁN RETROCEDIDOS
```

To archieve this, this is the code I wrote.

```
m = 0
f_out = open('C:/out_file.ini', "w")
with open('C:/in_file.ini') as f_in:
    lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)
    for i in lines:
        f_out.write('alm_siem_alarm' + str(m) + '=' + i.split(' "')[1][:-1].upper() + '\n')
        m = m + 1

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

The file `in_file.ini` contains some empty lines so I've to ignore them thats why I'm using the `list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)` you can see the code above.

**My problem is that I can't uppercase the non-ASCII characters** as `á`. So the output in `out_file.ini` is:

```
alm_siem_alarm0=LA MáQUINA DEBE DE ESTAR SIN PIEZA
alm_siem_alarm1=LOS AUTOCALIBRADOS NO ESTáN RETROCEDIDOS
```

I tried solving this by adding `.decode('utf-8').upper()` to the `i.split(' "')[1][:-1]` string but I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

Can someone give me a hand and tell me how can I uppercase all the words and get the desired output?

Comment: how many specials characters like `á` in the file? try `.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Does that matters? The in file contains more than 2000 lines and some lines contain 0 special characters and some other up to 3.

Comment: I already tried that too, I get the same error as the one of the question.

Comment: `.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8')` would work. Could you paste your code which failed

Comment: you have the code in the post. I already told you that I tried the `.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8')` and it takes the same error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte` . Which is the same error I'm getting with the code you pasted in the answer.

Comment: `f_out.write(
                'alm_siem_alarm' + str(m) + '=' + i.split(' "')[1][:-1].decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8') + '\n')` works, try it again.

Comment: No, it's not working. Sorry.

Comment: It's not working, even if I change the `in` file to another string with an `á` in order to simplify the problem, it gives the same error.

Comment: `print '%s' % 'á'.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Replace 'á' with your string, works toooooo. So I don't understand why failed within file. Could you print `type` and `content` of lines before writing file to check your input.

Comment: I think you should figure out first in what **encoding** are stored those lines in your `in_file.ini` ?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using the `codecs` module and adding the `encoding='latin-1'` to the `input` and `ouput` file.

```
import codecs
m = 0
f_out = codecs.open('C:/out_file.ini', "w", encoding='latin-1')
with codecs.open('C:/in_file.ini', encoding='latin-1') as f_in:
    lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)
    for i in lines:
        f_out.write('alm_siem_alarm' + str(m) + '=' + i.split(' "')[1].upper() + '\n')
        m = m + 1

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

And using the solution of `LittleQ`, the code is:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('C:/in_file.ini', encoding='latin-1') as f_in, codecs.open('C:/out_file.ini', "w", encoding='latin-1') as f_out:
    print "Leyendo... " + str(f_in.name)
    generator = (l.split('"')[1].strip() for l in f_in.readlines() if l.strip())
    for i, line in enumerate(generator):
        f_out.write('alm_siem_alarm%d=%s\n' % (i, line.upper()))
```

Comment: So it was not `utf-8` after all, that's why I asked you to check `encoding` of your file, first

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code:

```
with open('C:/in_file.ini', 'r') as f_in, open('C:/out_file.ini', "w") as f_out:
    generator = (l.split('"')[1].strip() for l in f_in.readlines() if l.strip())
    for i, line in enumerate(generator):
        f_out.write('alm_siem_alarm%d=%s\n' % (
            i, line.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8')))
```

Due `file.write(str)`, we should convert the string to `str` type.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still getting the same error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @Borja I can print the line alone, looking into the `file.write`

Comment: What do you mean? The code gives the error I told you on the first comment.

Comment: @Borja worked for me with py2.7. paste your code in the post

Comment: I'm using 2.7 too and it's not working. I tried by deleting all the lines and leaving just the first two and it's not working either.